# Graphical interface integration problem in python program

Tags: python, terminal, console

I'm trying to integrate a python program into a graphical interface, in such a way that the queries and responses of the program appear in a kind of terminal of the graphical interface. But the responses appear in the system terminal instead of the GUI terminal. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.
I leave here the code

```
''''''
    def button_callback2(self):
        text = self.textbox_frame.get()
        modelo = self.radiobutton_frame.get()
        rapido = "Rápido" in self.checkbox_frame.get()
        distro = "Distro" in self.checkbox_frame.get()
        desktop = "Desktop" in self.checkbox_frame.get()
        process_command(None, text, modelo, rapido, distro, desktop)  # Agrega el argumento faltante
        self.textbox_frame.set("")  # Vaciar el campo de texto

    ''''''

class MyTextFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, values):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.values = values
        self.textbox = None

        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, fg_color="black", text_color="#09822D", font=('Cascadia Mono', 16))
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10, 160), pady=(10, 0), sticky="ew")
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, self.values[0])  # Insertar el texto predeterminado
        self.textbox.bind('<FocusIn>', self.clear_placeholder)  # Enlazar evento de clic al campo de texto
        self.textbox.bind('<Return>', lambda e: app.button_callback2())

    def clear_placeholder(self, event):
        # Borrar el texto de placeholder solo si es la primera vez que se recibe el foco
        if self.textbox.get("1.0", tk.END).strip() == self.values[0]:
            self.textbox.delete("1.0", tk.END)

    def get(self):
        return self.textbox.get("1.0", tk.END).strip()

    def set(self, value):
        self.textbox.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, value)


''''''

class MyTerminalFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, title):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title = title
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Configurar la primera columna para que se expanda
        self.output_text = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self)
        self.output_text.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

        self.title_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text=self.title, fg_color="gray30", corner_radius=6)
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0), sticky="ew")

        self.text_widget = self.output_text._textbox
        self.text_widget.configure(state='disabled')

    def add_output(self, output):  # Agrega el argumento 'output'
        self.text_widget.configure(state='normal')
        self.text_widget.insert(tk.END, output + "\n")
        self.text_widget.see(tk.END)
        self.text_widget.configure(state='disabled')


def handle_errors(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def f_internal(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            app.output_callback(str(e))
            sys.exit(-1)

    return f_internal


def process_command(ctx, command, modelo, rapido, distro, desktop):
    def run_code():
        try:
            respuesta = f'Comando recibido: {command}'
            app.output_callback(respuesta)
        except Exception as e:
            app.output_callback(str(e))

    ''''''

    frase_usuario = None

    if not frase_usuario:
        consola.print('[gray]Introduce \'Salir\' para salir[/gray]')

    solicitud = '\nSolicitud de Comando Deseado: '
    while True:
        if not frase_usuario:
            frase_usuario = utilidades.prompt_frase_usuario(
                solicitud,
                sesion,
                consola,
                completador=utilidades.PathCompleter(),
                estilo_compl=CompleteStyle.MULTI_COLUMN,
                bindings_teclado=configuracion.kb
            )

        if not frase_usuario:
            continue

       ''''''

        if not comandos:
            continue

        opciones = [
            'Reformular la pregunta',
            'Ejecutar la/s órden/es',
            'Copiar la/s órden/es al portapapeles',
            'Salir',
        ]
        preguntas = [
            inquirer.List('Siguiente', message='Elige una de las opciones',
                          choices=opciones)
        ]
        seleccion = inquirer.prompt(preguntas)['Siguiente']

        if seleccion == 'Reformular la pregunta':
            solicitud = 'Solicitud de Comando Revisada: '
            continue
        elif seleccion == 'Ejecutar la/s órden/es':
            consola.print('[bold blue]Ejecutando...\n[/bold blue]')

            for idx, cmd in enumerate(comandos):
                if cmd:
                    consola.print(
                        f'[bold blue]Ejecutando Comando [{idx + 1}]: '
                        f'{cmd}[/bold blue]'
                    )
                    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
        elif seleccion == 'Copiar la/s órden/es al portapapeles':
            utilidades.copiar_al_portapapeles(comandos)
            consola.print('[bold blue]Comando/s copiados al portapapeles[/bold blue]')
        else:
            consola.print('[bold blue]Hasta luego...\n[/bold blue]')
            sys.exit(0)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_code)
    thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).